# Why some extensions only show small icon on Chrome Store?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I browser or search on Chrome Store, some extensions show large picture , but some show just small icon (see in the picture, the ***amzvar*** extension only shows a tiny icon.) 
Is it based on popularity or where we can set it?

[image: amzvar extension show small icon]

Comment: Not a programming question. But the tiles are optional by the publisher.

Comment: Oh yes. I just figured out I could add that at developer dashboard (i.e. promotion tiles)

Comment: Yep, it's a promo image. The question was answered here already. Upgrade your google-fu :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am doing clean-up of my questions on SO. :-) Yes this question had been answered. I would need to add 'Promotion Tile'. Thanks @danierHerr. Cannot accept his answer in comment for some reason, so post answer by myself. Also, check out my extension if you like: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/amzvar-price-viewer-of-am/lgdhflflkpgfhhpgnpeocbfmmkijcckn

[image: Price Viewer of Amazon Variations - amzVar]